# How can i get list of called functions inside template?

Tags: php, symfony, templates, trace

I have templates which are edited on the web view and i can not know which functions are used inside the template.

Is there any possibility to get list of class, functions with their arguments used inside this template?

Comment: Parse the template, extract the functions?

Comment: The profiler could be interesting for you. https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#profiler-extension

Comment: `debug_backtrace()` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php